# Protege Stanford JessTab error

Tags: rules, ontology, stanford-nlp, protege, jess

im trying to explore n getting familiar with JessRules. i have installed jessrules ver 7 engine into protege 3.4.8.

first im creating person class without problem:

```
Jess> (defclass Person (is-a :THING)
      (slot name (type string))
      (slot age (type integer))) <enter>
TRUE
```

then im creating individual:

```
(make-instance john of Person (name "John") (age 20)) <enter>
```

then i got following response:

```
<Java-Object:edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.impl.DefaultOWLIndividual>
```

in tutorial should be:

```
<External-Address:SimpleInstance>
```

but the instance is successfully created. but when i do mapclass and facts command, some part in instance facts output will contains error too:

```
(MAIN::object (is-a Person) (is-a-name "Person") 
(OBJECT <Java-Object:edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.impl.DefaultOWLIndividual>)
(rdfs:label ) (owl:versionInfo ) (rdfs:comment ) (rdfs:member ) 
(:NAME "john") (rdfs:isDefinedBy ) (rdfs:seeAlso ) (owl:differentFrom ) 
(owl:sameAs ) (rdf:value ) (protege:inferredType ) 
(rdf:type <Java-Object:edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.impl.DefaultOWLNamedClass>) 
(name "John") (age 20))
```

im not sure about this error. i have already try to google and didnt find any clue. thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are no "errors" here; it's just that JessTab and Protege have evolved over the years since your tutorial was written, and the names of some classes have changed.

Comment: thanks for the response,  btw it is better to downgrade the version? when i do slot-get (slot name that contains instances) it wont shows instance name. any idea to shows the instances name through jess?